# pythoin and json - ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)

Tags: python, json

wowee...and the python with json is what?
I get the below string from poping a redis queue that was generated by dumping a dictionary into a json string and placing in a list.  when I pop..wow..I get the below

```
args = {'series': 'exr|usd|gbp', 'K': 2, 'M': 2, 'tau': 1}
args = json.loads(args)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/chaos/chaos_worker.py", line 12, in <module>
    args = json.loads(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wait, are you converting a python dict into json? In that case use `json.dumps`. The `args` as you have defined on first line is in fact a `dict`.

```
args = {'series': 'exr|usd|gbp', 'K': 2, 'M': 2, 'tau': 1}
print args.__class__
Out: dict
args = json.dumps(args)
print args
Out: '{"series": "exr|usd|gbp", "K": 2, "M": 2, "tau": 1}'
```

In json parsable string as expected.